# Multiple User Defined Exceptions in java

Tags: java, exception

So the scenario is to limit a user to perform three transactions a day, I wanted to finish the part where the exception is to be raised any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class FundsNotAvailable extends Exception{
FundsNotAvailable(String s){
super(s);
}
}
class ExceededTransactionsLimit extends Exception{
ExceededTransactionsLimit(String s){
super(s);
}
}
class BankMethods {
String accName;
String accNumber;
Integer balance;
public Integer transactions = 0;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
void AccOpen()
{
    System.out.println("Enter Account Holder Name: ");
    accName = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter Account Number: ");
    accNumber = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the Deposit amount: ");
    balance = sc.nextInt();
    
}

void Deposit()
{
    Integer amount;
    System.out.println("Enter the Amount you wish to Deposit:");
    amount = sc.nextInt();
    balance = balance + amount;
}

void Withdrawal() throws FundsNotAvailable, ExceededTransactionsLimit
{
    Integer amount;
    System.out.println("Enter the Amount you wish to Withdraw:");
    amount = sc.nextInt();
    if (amount > balance)
    {
        throw new FundsNotAvailable("Insufficient Funds");
    }
    if(transactions > 3)
    {
        throw new ExceededTransactionsLimit("You have exceeded the daily transactions limit");
    }
    balance = balance - amount;
    System.out.println(transactions);
}

void showBalance()
{
    System.out.println("The Balance in your Account is:" + balance);
}
    
}
public class Bank
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    BankMethods BM = new BankMethods();
    BM.AccOpen();
    Integer choice;
    do {
        System.out.println("Main Menu \n 1. Deposit \n 2. Withdraw \n 3. Show Balance \n 4. Exit");
        System.out.println("Please Make A Choice:");
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            BM.Deposit();
            break;
        case 2:
            try {
                BM.Withdrawal();
            } catch (ExceededTransactionsLimit | FundsNotAvailable e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            
            break;
        case 3:
            BM.showBalance();
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Good Bye");
            break;
        }
    }
    while (choice != 4);    
}

}
```

the condition transactions > 3 is working fine when i run it in the main class but isnt throwing an exception when i run it in the method i even tried to keep track of the transcations variable value and it kept increasing everytime i performed the withdraw operation.

Thank you (any help is appreciated)

Comment: You forgot to ask the question, please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Probably because you never change the value of variable `transactions`.

Answer (score 0):

no where in the code, value of `transactions` variable is getting updated.
Please add `transactions++;` in your `Withdrawal()` function and it will start working.